# Socket.io emits message to all clients except the one that initially emitted the original message

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have two or more clients connected to the Socket.io room, client #1 emits message like so:

```
export function appendChild({ item }){
  socket.emit(APPEND_CHILD, { item })
  return {
    type: APPEND_CHILD,
  }
}
```

this successfully sent message to the server which looks like this:

```
socket.on('APPEND_CHILD', async ({ item }) => {
  ...
  socket.in(socket.handshake.query.room).emit('APPEND_CHILD_AFTER_EFFECT', { payload: { log, parentLog }, socketId: socket.id })
})
```

Please note that to trigger this, I use one message type, and to ping all clients for the update, I use different message, which when sent, should be received by all clients and they shall all update their state.

Clients listen for incoming messages like this:

```
socket.on('APPEND_CHILD_AFTER_EFFECT', ({ payload, socketId }) => {
        console.log('test !')
        ...
      })
```

**All clients except the active (the one that sent initial emit) received message.**

Why didn't main client receive message and how to make it so?

Comment: Seems logical to me that the client that sent the event wouldn't need the notification...

Comment: @James That is true in most cases, but there are scenarios you want it otherwise, especially if you need some data from the server. In my case specifically, I needed client to request action, and then server would use client's input and create object, then send that object to all clients so that they can update their UI, including the sender. (that way I avoid duplicating logic for object creation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @guico33 from Discord have noticed I've used `socket` object rather than `io` when emitting to all clients.

```
io.on('connect', socket => {
    socket.on('event', message => { 
        socket.in(room).emit(...) 
    })
})
```

It should look like so:

```
  io.in(socket.handshake.query.room).emit(message, data)
```

rather than:

```
  socket.in(socket.handshake.query.room).emit(message, data)
```

Instead of `socket.in(room).emit(...)`, I should've used `io.in(room).emit(...)` to send the response to everyone including the emitter.